# compile error-Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I've been working on my android location project and after I pasted the placeAutocompleteAdapter and started building the project but I get this compiler error of this.
I've been able to resolve the problem above but after running my project, the app crashed on launch and after checking the logcat I found this error

```
(06-01 12:54:33.920 30570-30570/com.example.sachiewerk.nearby_place E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sachiewerk.nearby_place, PID: 30570
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbo;
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5545)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5484)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sachiewerk.nearby_place-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.sachiewerk.nearby_place-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5974) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5545) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5484) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1595) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924) 
)
```

. Can anyone help me out? I don't know where this error came from because I tried checking my build.gradle file but didn't find any error there.
Below is the build.gradle`enter code here`

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sachiewerk.nearby_place"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
}
```

Comment: please add your *app* `build.gradle` in your question.

Comment: I've been able to resolve the first problem I faced so I've updated the question along with my build.gradle

Comment: You have conflicted play service library, try removing the following line:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'`

Comment: thanks ישו אוהב אותך, I have been able to run it now.

Comment: Great! Let me make it as an answer then you can mark it as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the same version of Google Play Service. In your build.gradle, you have multiple dependencies of Google play service. You need to remove the following line:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
```

Furthermore, you must not use the above code because it includes all the play service library. Instead, [follow this rule](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> Don't use the combined play-services target. It brings in dozens of
>   libraries, bloating your application. Instead, specify only the
>   specific Google Play services APIs your app uses.